# Issue with POST request: Validation Error in Express and Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, validation, sequelize.js, postman

I'm encountering an issue while trying to send a POST request to create a task in my Express.js application using Sequelize as the ORM. I've followed the setup and validation rules, but I keep getting a validation error in Postman. I've double-checked my code, but I can't seem to find the source of the problem. Can someone please help me troubleshoot and understand what might be causing this?

Code Structure:

Here's an overview of my application's folder structure:

```
- app/
  - src/
    - accounts/
      - models/
        - users.js
      - routes/
        - users.js
    - tasks/
      - models/
        - tasks.js
      - routes/
        - tasks.js
      - controllers/
        - tasks.js
    - config/
      - db.js
      - validate.js
    - index.js
  - node_modules/
  - package.json
  - package-lock.json
```

Schema (tasks.js):

```
const tasksSchema = {
    title: {
        notEmpty: true,
        errorMessage: "Title cannot be empty",
        isLength: {
            options: { min: 3 },
            errorMessage: "Title must contain at least 3 characters"
        }
    },
    content: {
        optional: true, // This field is optional, but if present, will be validated
        isLength: {
            options: { max: 5000 }, // Maximum length of 5000 characters
            errorMessage: "Content must not exceed 5000 characters"
        }
    },

    userId: {
        notEmpty: true,
        errorMessage: "userId cannot be empty",
        isInt: {
            errorMessage: "userId must be an integer"
        }
    }
};


module.exports = { tasksSchema};
```

Controllers (tasks.js):

```
const { Task } = require('../models/tasks');
const TaskService = require('../services/tasks');
const TaskSupport = require('../supports/tasks');

const createTask = async (req, res) => {
    const task = req.body;

    try {
        const createdTask = await TaskService.createTask(task);
        console.log('createTask: createdTask:', createdTask);

        if (createdTask.error) {
            console.log('createTask: Error creating task:', createdTask.error);
            return res.status(400).send(createdTask);
        }

        const responseTask = await TaskSupport.buildTaskResponse(createdTask);
        console.log('createTask: Response task:', responseTask);
        
        return res.status(201).send(responseTask);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error creating task:', err);

        if (err.status) {
            return res.status(err.status).json({
                message: err.message,
            });
        }

        return res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Error on server',
        });
    }
};

module.exports = {
    createTask,
}
```

Model (tasks.js):

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../../config/db');
const { User } = require('../../accounts/models/users');

const Task = sequelize.define('tasks', {
    title: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    content: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT
    } ,
    completed:{
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
    } , 
    creationDate:{
        type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
    }, 
    completitionDate:{
        type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
        allowNull: true, 
        defaultValue: null 
    },

}

);

Task.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'userId' }); 

module.exports = {
    Task
}
```

Routes (tasks.js):

```
const router = require('express').Router({ mergeParams: true });
const { createTask} = require('../controllers/tasks');
const { validate } = require('./../../config/validate');
const { checkSchema } = require('express-validator');
const { tasksSchema} = require('../schemas/tasks');

// Create task route with validation and controller
router.post('/', validate(checkSchema(tasksSchema)), createTask);

module.exports = {
    router,
};
```

Index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const { router: usersRoutes } = require('./src/accounts/routes/users');
const { router: tasksRoutes } = require('./src/tasks/routes/tasks');
const sequelize = require('./src/config/db');

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

// Routes
app.use('/api/users', usersRoutes);
app.use('/api/tasks', tasksRoutes);

// Database synchronization
sequelize.sync()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Database is synced');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error syncing database:', error);
  });

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 80; // Use environment variable if available
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

Issue:

When I send a POST request to http://localhost:80/api/tasks/ with the following JSON body:

```json
{
    "title": "Buy groceries",
    "content": "Buy milk, bread, and eggs.",
    "userId": 2
}
```

I receive the following validation error in Postman:

```json
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "type": "field",
            "msg": "Title cannot be empty",
            "path": "title",
            "location": "body"
        },
        {
            "type": "field",
            "msg": "Title must contain at least 3 characters",
            "path": "title",
            "location": "body"
        },
        {
            "type": "field",
            "msg": "userId cannot be empty",
            "path": "userId",
            "location": "body"
        },
        {
            "type": "field",
            "msg": "userId must be an integer",
            "path": "userId",
            "location": "body"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've already confirmed that my validation schema is correctly defined, and I've tried restarting the server and Postman. What could be causing this error? Is there something I'm missing in my setup or validation logic? Also, I tried to use the "console.log()" debugging to try to know what's happening but I'm not getting any message in my terminal

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: _"with the following JSON body"_... does the request also have the appropriate `content-type` header?

Comment: _"When I send a POST request to `http://localhost:80/api/tasks/`"_... try without the trailing `/`

Comment: Add a test middleware prior to `validate` one and output JSON.stringify(req.body) to console there